# how to set the min-height and max-height in slimScroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to add min-height and max-height in slimScroll plugin? I applying this plugin in text area , the textarea max-height reach it need to be scroll, textarea by default min-height 120px and max-height 200px

```
<script>
     $(".editTextarea").slimScroll({
                    color: '#e5e5e5',
                    position: 'right',
                    alwaysVisible: false
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the source code you can see the default option

```
 var defaults = {
    //Add these lines in your plugin source code
      minHeight:'auto',
      minWidth:'auto'


    width : 'auto',


    height : '250px',


    size : '7px',

    color: '#000',


    position : 'right',


    distance : '1px',


    start : 'top',


    opacity : .4,


    alwaysVisible : false,


    disableFadeOut : false,


    railVisible : false,


    railColor : '#333',


    railOpacity : .2,


    railDraggable : true,


    railClass : 'slimScrollRail',


    barClass : 'slimScrollBar',


    wrapperClass : 'slimScrollDiv',


    allowPageScroll : false,


    wheelStep : 20,


    touchScrollStep : 200,


    borderRadius: '7px',

    railBorderRadius : '7px'
  };
```

i think you cannot add min-height and min-width through the plugin there are two options

- study the source code and then add extra style attribute
- or/ try to use css

add the commented lines in your source line (164 and 176)
    var wrapper = $(divS)
              .addClass(o.wrapperClass)
              .css({
                position: 'relative',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                width: o.width,
                height: o.height
               /*
                min-heigth:o.minHeight,
                min-width:o.minWidth
               */
              });

```
        // update style for the div
        me.css({
          overflow: 'hidden',
          width: o.width,
          height: o.height,
          /*
          min-heigth:o.minHeight,
          min-width:o.minWidth
          */
        });
```

Comment: yes , not add min-height, max-height in that plugin, but i need that one in plugin, how i can do? scroll once reach max-height then it is visible using this plugin

Comment: is there any other way to add min and max height

Comment: is min-height and min-width  static.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand but I think what you are saying is to make the `textarea` only scrollable when it exceeds the `max-height` you want to set? You can not do that by default but you can change some of the source code.

```
height: o.height and change to 'max-height': o.height (line: 156 and 163)
```

Described in more detail in this thread: https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/70

Comment: can you so me on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

set `height: auto` and set the parent min-height

```html
<div class='parent' style='min-height:400px;'>
   <div class='scroll'>
     //content
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
 $(".scroll").slimScroll({
        height: 'auto'
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trick for me.

```js
$("xxx").slimScroll({
  size: '8px',
  width: '100%',
  height: 'fit-content',
  color: '#ff4800',
  allowPageScroll: true,
  alwaysVisible: false,
  railVisible: true,
  // scroll amount applied to each mouse wheel step
  wheelStep: 20,
  // scroll amount applied when user is using gestures
  touchScrollStep: 200,
  // distance in pixels between the side edge and the scrollbar
  //distance: '10px',
}).css("max-height", "50vh").parent().css("max-height", "50vh");
```